# AWS - is there a way to receive events asynchronously without the lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a general AWS question. I have started using AWS sdk, but looks like if I want to receive events asynchronously from AWS(ex: cloudwatch events), lambda functions is the only way. I want to write a simple application that registers a callback to AWS for events, but i couldn't find a way to do that till now, since i don't want to use lambda, i have been polling from my application. Please, let me know if polling is the only option or if there is a better way to resolve it without polling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html):

You can configure the following AWS services as targets for CloudWatch Events:

```
Amazon EC2 instances
AWS Lambda functions
Streams in Amazon Kinesis Streams
Delivery streams in Amazon Kinesis Firehose
Amazon ECS tasks
SSM Run Command
SSM Automation
Step Functions state machines
Pipelines in AWS CodePipeline
Amazon Inspector assessment templates
Amazon SNS topics
Amazon SQS queues
Built-in targets
The default event bus of another AWS account
```

That's **a lot** more than just Lambda, so I'm not sure why you state in your question that Lambda is the only option. The options of `Amazon EC2 instances` and `Amazon SNS topics` both provide a method for Amazon to "push" the events to your services, instead of requiring your services to poll.

Comment: thanks for the info. I tried SNS,  just learned that i can push the notification to http/https endpoint. I can't find how to use a Amazon EC2 instances as a target

Comment: Yeah the EC2 instances thing in that document doesn't make much sense now that I think about it. I believe that's only certain EC2 actions that can be triggered by certain CloudWatch events like EC2 status failures. SNS is definitely the way to go for your use case.

Comment: is it possible to run the rest endpoint on a ec2 on its private ip and provide that endpoint with private ip in SNC subscriber

Comment: @PMat not to my knowledge. I think you could do signature verification, and reject any messages that fail: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.verify.signature.html Of course if you weren't so averse to using Lambda it would be easy to setup CloudWatch Events to trigger a Lambda function that has VPC access, and then that Lambda function could hit an HTTP endpoint on your private EC2 server. You should think of AWS services as building blocks, and Lambda as the glue that holds them together.

Answer (score 3):

With [cloudwatch events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html), you can set rules and trigger a number of different targets, including SQS queues which you can poll from your EC2 Instances.

Lambda is certainly a popular endpoint, but based on the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html), there are other targets you can send the events to

Comment: i knew about that, i don't want to poll, i am trying not to do polling

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Lambda is typically the right solution for responding to cloudwatch events. Any reason you don't want to use Lambda?

Comment: we want to see if we can bypass lambda. The question is basically about the SDK. In my case I am using GOlang. I don't see a callback methods except polling getevents periodically

Comment: As of 2018-01-15 [Go](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/01/aws-lambda-supports-go/) is supported

Answer (score 2):

Already above answers might also be helpful, but one of the possible options to address your problem could be one of this as well.

You can make use of AWS SNS service to subscribe for the events on AWS resources. And the SNS can publish the events to your application end point. Which is nothing but pub/sub model.

Refer this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html

The end-point could be your http or https based application.